# Как можно распаковать\получить инфу о файлах архива в C++?

Tags: c++, zip, архивация, rar

Архивы форматов rar,zip, необходимо: распаковывать архив, получать определенный фаил из архива, получать древо каталогов и список всех файлов архива.

Есть библиотеки для подобной работы с архивами? и как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Долго искать не надо :) - в Википедии и то есть: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlib

Comment: Скачайте zlib или pkzip для линукса исходники, там всё доступно и понятно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я думаю, что `zlib` - это слишком низкоуровневое решение для Вас, я бы Вам порекомендовал `libzip` - она построена на базе `zlib`, но с её помощью Вы гораздо проще разберёте файл с архивом. Как её установить я описывать не буду (ведь Вы не указали Вашу операционную систему и прочие требования), поэтому приведу пример, как с её помощью пробежаться по всем файлам архива и извлечь их. Сперва подключите следующие заголовочный файлы:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <zip.h>
```

Функция, которая считывает данные из текущего элемента архива и записывает их в отдельный файл:

```
static int writeCurrentFile(int i, struct zip *za, struct zip_stat zipStat, char bufForFileName[]) {

    struct zip_file *zipFile; // Структура для работы с текущим файлом архива
    int fd; // Файловый дескриптор
    zip_int64_t lenOfReadData; // Сколько байт было прочитано из файла
    char buf[512]; // Буфер для чтения информации из архива

    zipFile = zip_fopen_index(za, i, 0);
    if (!zipFile) {

        return 1;
    }
    fd = open(bufForFileName, O_RDWR | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, 0644); //Создать файл
    if (fd < 0) { // Если файл нельзя создать, значит произошла ошибка

        zip_fclose(zipFile);
        return 1;
    }
    zip_uint64_t sum = 0; // Полный размер текущего файла в архиве
    while (sum != zipStat.size) {

        lenOfReadData = zip_fread(zipFile, buf, sizeof(buf) * sizeof(buf[0]));
        if (lenOfReadData < 0) {

            zip_fclose(zipFile);
            return 1;
        }
        write(fd, buf, lenOfReadData);
        sum += lenOfReadData;
    }
    close(fd);
    int zipCloseResult = zip_fclose(zipFile);
    if (zipCloseResult != 0) {

        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Функция последовательно проходится по всем элементам открытого файла с архивом:

```
static int loopThroughFiles(const char* archiveRoot, struct zip *za) {

    int i; // Переменная для итерирования
    struct zip_stat zipStat; // Информация о файле
    size_t currentItemNameLength; // Длина имени текущего элемента в архиве

    for (i = 0; i < zip_get_num_entries(za, 0); i++) {

        if (zip_stat_index(za, i, 0, &zipStat) == 0) {

            currentItemNameLength = strlen(zipStat.name);
            printf("Имя файла: [%s], ", zipStat.name);
            printf("Размер: [%llu], ", zipStat.size);
            printf("\n");
            char bufForFileName[300]; // Буфер для имени файла с учётом корневой папки
            strcpy(bufForFileName, archiveRoot);
            strcat(bufForFileName, zipStat.name);
            if (zipStat.name[currentItemNameLength - 1] == '/') { // Если текущий элемент архива - папка, то нужно создать папку на диске

                if (mkdir(bufForFileName, S_IRWXU | S_IRGRP | S_IXGRP | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH) < 0) { // Если не удалось создать папку
                    if (errno != EEXIST) { // Если не удалось создать папку по причине того, что она уже была создана, то всё нормально, иначе завершим программу

                        return 1;
                    }
                }
            } else { // Текущий элемент - файл, а значит нужно последовательно считать все данные и записать их на диск

                writeCurrentFile(i, za, zipStat, bufForFileName);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Главная функция для работы с архивом:

```
int enumerateArchive(const char* filePath, const char* archiveRoot) {

    struct zip *za;// Структура для работы с архивом
    int err; // Код последней ошибки
    // Попытаться открыть файл с архивом, если не получилось - сообщить об ощибке
    if ((za = zip_open(filePath, ZIP_CREATE | ZIP_RDONLY, &err)) == NULL) {

        return 1;
    }
    // Пройтись по всем элементам архива
    loopThroughFiles(archiveRoot, za);
    // Закрыть файл с архивом (если не получилось - сообщить об ошибке)
    if (zip_close(za) == -1) {

        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Потом вызовете данную функцию:

```
enumerateArchive("Путь/к/вашему/файлу.zip");
```